# Hitting enter at virtual keyboard does not fire any event at all

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-virtual-keyboard

Here is my code:

```
searchEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                Toast.makeText(AlapSlidingActivity.this, "keycode: "+keyCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

For some reason this code executes well on my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, and it is toasts the message for hitting enter: "keycode: 66"

But with an Alcatel onetouch it is not toasts anything. For hitting back button, both devices toasts "keycode: 4" that is fine, but hitting "enter" on the Alcatel does nothinh.

Any ideas?

Comment: are those hard keys or soft?

Comment: What do you mean by hard or soft ? It is a virtual keyboard at the screen.

Comment: ok - that's a soft keyboard (hard = physical keyboard). What happens when you trigger the toast with a different KeyEvent? For what you're doing, I'd use onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) { ... case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: Toast... }